# Rails 3 console taking 10+ minutes to load (and never loads)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I'm new to Rails. I am making my way through literature and have just stumbled across the 'rails console' command.

When I type that in, I get:

> Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.7)

In turn, the development environment never loads. I've waited quite a few minutes, too.

I did see some of the other related posts to this topic/problem, but in all instances, it seemed that individuals were trying to speed up their environment load time -- not simply get their environment to load in the first place.

As for my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.7'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)

gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.1', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:

# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

Comment: Some questions that may help people debug this: What's in your Gemfile? How new/fast is your computer? Is the app new/old, small/large?

Comment: Does this happen on a brand new application as well?

Comment: Pasting my gemfile was kind of a pain, sorry for the poor formatting. My computer: brand new, MacBook Pro. The app is pretty new, I've just been messing around with it a bit -- it's the demo_app that is built in Michael Hartl's Ruby Tutorial Book. | This seems to happen with all/any app, new or old.

Comment: How is your ram ? Please check out the memory usage of your system. This sounds like a memory prolbme.

Comment: 4 Gigs of Ram. Free ram is 1.61 without running the console command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would install RVM and not use the built in Ruby etc.

[Install RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/)

Comment: I seem to be having an issue with installing a particular Ruby version via rvm. When I input "rvm install 1.9.2, "-bash: /Users/alexandertandy/.rvm/scripts/manage: Permission denied" is returned to me. But without troubleshooting that too much, do you think rvm will solve my problem of not being able to boot up the rails console?

Comment: Yes, you'll be doing a fresh install if rails onto the ruby of your choice

Comment: I think that did the trick. While installing RVM was not particularly easy, I actually got through the installation steps without a problem, but didn't see anywhere indicating that I needed to type "gem install rails" or "bundle install" following the proper installation. Prior to that, I was receiving a slew of different errors, including a depracation error, "as well as a Could not find diff-lcs-1.1.2 in any of the sources". Anyway, seems to all work now. Thanks for the suggestion, Nick.

Answer (score 2):

Just update your bundler, it may be of any of the older gems is conflicting with latest one, this type of issues arises.

```
'gem install bundler'
```

and then `'bundle install'`

If you find again error, then delete the Gemfile.lock file, then run `bundle install`. It may resolve the issue.

Comment: Hey Napster, thanks for the suggestion, but alas, it did not work. I deleted the GEM.lock file, then ran bundler install with this command (as it forced me to because of the need for permissions): 'sudo gem install bundler'. Everything seemed to update properly -- no errors received. I wasn't, however, able to use the specific command you mentioned: 'bundler install'

Comment: Did your problem was solved. or still issue is there. Plz write the issue in comment box..

Comment: The problem has not yet been solved. I was able to execute the bundler install command, eventually, and it didn't fix the problem. I still just sit waiting for the console to load up, but it never does.